# Plural of nouns like "sensitivity", "software"

Tags: grammatical-number

This question has the same background as my [previous one](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/319073/). I am struggling with countable/uncountable nouns. I am reviewing a document, containing the following sentences:

> Cross-verification of softwares for ...
>
> Sensitivities of A and B to the variation of C have been investigated.

My gut-feeling tells me neither *software* nor *sensitivity* should be used in plural here. But while *software* is simply uncountable, *sensitivity* is not. So I am struggling to find an explanation for this feeling.

Typically I'd say, that if we are talking about two different *kinds* of sensitivity (though I'd struggle to think of an example), then *sensitivities* is possible. But when it's just how sensitive A and B are to the variation of C, it's so to say one sensitivity type and therefore cannot be used in plural.

Am I right? Is there a way to determine it next time (they love using plural like this over here in my company) without asking on SE?

**Note:** I know how to help my colleague avoid "softwares" and also the motivation (uncountable noun). The question is about "sensitivities", and I keep the "softwares" sentence in to provide the context: People over here like using plurals a lot, and I often feel they are overdoing it. The problem for me is that I am afraid I can overdo it the other way round. I don't want to ask the document author to rephrase "sensitivities" unless it is really wrong.

Comment: Sensitivities is countable but software is not. Perhaps use "Cross-verification of software *packages*" to make it countable?

Comment: @Ste: I realize the duplication with the software question. However my question is not about how to avoid "softwares". I only kept that sentence to illustrate the context :) I've updated the question accordingly, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

"Software" (in US English, at least) is never pluralized.  One might say "software packages" as suggested by Ste.

"Sensitivity" may be pluralized in some cases.  In

> Sensitivities of A and B to the variation of C have been investigated.

the plural would be used if you are speaking of separate measurements of the sensitivity of A to C and B to C.  But the singular would be used if you didn't really treat them as separate measurements.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're correct that 'software' is uncountable.

Go ahead and use "the sensitivity of A and B to C..."

One of the guidelines for using plural nouns in a group is if they share something. If the objects in a group share a common trait/item, then use the singular for that shared thing. In this case, A and B both have a sensitivity to the same thing (C), so you can use the singular form of 'sensitivity.'

> The students greatly admire their teacher. (All the admiring students have the same teacher.)

If the items in a group have a common trait but it isn't actually shared, you would use the plural form of the shared item.

> The students greatly admire their teachers. (The students are alike in
>   their admiration of a teacher, but they have different teachers. Or possibly multiple shared teachers.)

I couldn't come up with an example of "sensitivities" on my own, so I turned to the Internet. In this case, a single person has a sensitivity to many disparate foods. And really, "food sensitivities" is probably the most common use of the plural.

> It would know all my food sensitivities and alert me if a single bite
>   had these substances in it. Read more at
>   http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/sensitivities#CVU7ziKDUkclLaeO.99

You may want to re-write the sentence: "The sensitivity of both A and B to C..." Using quantifiers like 'each' or 'both' can help avoid ambiguity and make other grammar questions easier/moot.

Comment: You failed to explain when the plural of "sensitivity" might be used.